# How can I extract text from several pdf links?

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, web-scraping

I have the main link, from which I get several links with pdfs. I and trying to find a way to extract the text from these pdf files. My code does not extract all the text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
 
url = 'https://oeil.secure.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/popups/ficheprocedure.do?reference=2014/0124(COD)&l=en'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
 
urls = []
for link in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("AM")):
    page_url = str(link.get('href'))
    pdf_url = page_url.replace('.html', '.pdf')
    print(pdf_url)
    urls.append(pdf_url)
```

```
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    f = io.BytesIO(r.content)
    reader = PdfFileReader(f)
    contents = reader.getPage(0)
    text = contents.extractText()
    with Path('pdf.txt').open(mode='w') as output_file:
        pdf = ''
        for page in reader.pages:
            pdf += page.extractText()
        
        output_file.write(pdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer

Let's start by creating a separate function to just get all text from a PDF, which is provided as a `Path`. Feel free to change it, should you need it as a URL.

```py
from borb.toolkit import SimpleTextExtraction
from borb.pdf import PDF

def get_text_from_pdf(p: Path) -> str:

    # process PDF
    l: SimpleTextExtraction = SimpleTextExtraction()
    with open(p, "rb") as fh:
        PDF.loads(fh, [l])

    # return
    return "".join([(v+"\n") for k,v in l.get_text().items()])
```

Now you can simply call this method several times (once for each file in a directory for instance).

`borb` is an open source, pure Python PDF library that creates, modifies and reads PDF documents. You can download it using:

```
pip install borb
```

Alternatively, you can build from source by forking/downloading the [GitHub](https://www.github.com/jorisschellekens/borb) repository.